# How to update object in rails table by replacing it with another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have images in a rails table. The table has a fixed number of images, so when an image is uploaded, it is not appended to the end of the table, but instead replaces one of the images already in the table (update).

Here is my form for collecting the image:

```
<%= form_for :image, url: images_path do |f| %> 

  <p>
    <%= f.file_field :file %> 
  </p> 

  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="image[id]" value="1">1 
    <input type="radio" name="image[id]" value="2">2
    <input type="radio" name="image[id]" value="3">3
  </p>

  <p><%= f.submit "submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my `create` action that the form calls:

```
def create 
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    image = Image.find_by(id: image_params["id"])
    image = @image

    if image.save 
        redirect_to '/'
    else 
        render 'links/new'
    end
end 

private 

    def image_params
        params.require(:image).permit(:file, :id)
    end
```

This producing the following error however:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique: INSERT INTO "images"
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this properly?

Answer (score 2):

This error is happening because you are copying the existing image to a new image instance which has no id. Naturally the database will throw a primary key exception. Why are you doing it this way? Why don't you update the existing image?

If you must, you can delete the old image before saving the new one.

```
@image = Image.new(image_params)
@image.id = old_image.id
old_image.delete
@image.save
```

But this is an ugly, hackish way to do it. You also have no transactions to guarantee rolling back the DB in case something fails.

Why not update the existing image instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use form_for to just receive an image that I can use to update the file attribute of the existing image in the database. Can I just extract the picture from the form_for hash and use that to update the existing Image object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But you should be able to use `form_for @image` where `@image` is the existing image instance. You would need `edit` and `update` actions in the controller, and route their respective routes. Then Rails will automatically pick up the model data and let you replace the URL.